# Using multiple imageview from one source

Tags: android, imageview

I have one Imageview in my `activity_main.xml` and I'd like to draw two from this in a different position. I tried this without succes:

```
    image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    image2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) image.getLayoutParams();
    LayoutParams params2 = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) image2.getLayoutParams();

    params.topMargin = 50;
        params.leftMargin = 50;
        image.setLayoutParams(params);

        params2.topMargin = 100;
        params2.leftMargin = 100;
        image2.setLayoutParams(params2);
```

It draws just one piece. I also tried the `setImageBitmap`:

```
image2.setImageBitmap(((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap());
```

How should I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only seeing one `ImageView` because there is only one `ImageView` in your layout. Both `image` and `image2` reference the same id (`R.id.imageView1`) in your layout:

```
image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
image2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
```

You can solve this 2 ways as I see it:

1. Inflate your `ImageView`s one at a time and add them to your layout at runtime. This is a bit more complicated for what you are trying to do.
2. Add another `ImageView` to your xml layout (set the id to `R.id.imageView2`) with the appropriate margins you want. Then just reference each `ImageView` in code and edit them separately.

Solution #2 would look something like this in your code (after adding a 2nd `ImageView` to your xml layout):

```
image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
image2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
```

Comment: I had to use myLayout.addView(image2) and it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can't re-use the same ImageView like that. You need to add another ImageView to your layout xml file:

```
<ImageView
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/imageView2" />
```

and then change this line:

```
image2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
```

to this:

```
image2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
```

also on a side note, you should avoid using names like `imageView1` and `imageView2`. Those are not descriptive at all, they make it harder to understand what it is that your code is actually doing. Consider using variable names that are more descriptive of what the variable does. It will make your code easier to understand and maintain.